# Celery didn't operate well because of errno 104

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a problem executing celery on rabbitmq-server. I searched and found [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610991/consumer-connection-error-with-django-and-celeryrabbitmq), but it doesn't help me.
My env is ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.6, celery 3.1.15, Django 1.7.
Referencing [a link](http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html), I installed rabbitmq-server locally. I added user, vhost in rabbitmq-server and set permissions.

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl add_user tonyg password
$ sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost vir_host
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p vir_host tonyg ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

My celery's setting in django follows.

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://tonyg:password@localhost:5672//vir_host'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://tonyg:password@localhost:5672//vir_host'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = [u'application/x-python-serialize', u'image/jpeg', u'image/bmp', u'image/png', u'image/tiff']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
```

I don't set anything about rabbitmq-server other than default configs.

I executed celery like this.

```
$ celery -A MyProj worker -l info

-------------- celery@ip-172-31-3-10 v3.1.15 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         MyProj:0x7f7453328b10
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://tonyg:**@localhost:5672//vir_host
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://tonyg:password@localhost:5672//vir_host
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . MyProj.tasks. ......
  . MyProj.tasks. ......

[2014-10-29 15:07:50,241: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://tonyg:**@127.0.0.1:5672//vir_host: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2014-10-29 15:07:55,251: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://tonyg:**@127.0.0.1:5672//vir_host: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
```

When i set celery using default guest identifier,

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

it does operate well. I don't know why. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run `rabbitmqctl list_vhosts`. The output will be:

```
Listing vhosts ...
/
vir_host
...done.
```

Thus the URL has to be:

```
amqp://tonyg:**@localhost:5672/vir_host
```

Comment: Url is correct. But the user doesn't have admin privileges to connect via virtual host.

Comment: @Krzysztof Szularz Thank you so much. I thought i have tried amqp://tonyg:**@localhost:5672/vir_host. But, I tried again. It does work!!! I made a silly mistake. But, i wanna know why setting (amqp://tonyg:**@localhost:5672/vir_host) does operate well in a Mac OS X. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: I don't get the question. `amqp://tonyg:**@localhost:5672/vir_host` operates well because it's a valid URL for vhost you've created. The one with two slashes is not a valid one, unless vhost is called `/vir_host` which isn't the case.

Comment: @Krzysztof Szularz I typed wrong url. I can't modify comment after 5 mins. I set BROKER_URL = 'amqp://tonyg:password@localhost:5672//vir_host' on Mac OS X, but it does work correctly. Do u know why?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz i sincerely apologize. its my mistake  @BlueFrog your virual host name is might be `/vir_host` but not `vir_host`

Comment: @ChillarAnand Thank you, you're right. My virtual host name is '/vir_host' on Mac OS x. It is my mistake. T_T  Maybe i might see 'sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost /vir_host' in a tutorial. I have followed that direction.

Comment: Note if your hostname changes rabbitmq has to be completely removed using `sudo apt-get purge rabbitmq-server` and then reinstalled.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @[Krzysztof Szularz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085511/krzysztof-szularz)  answer. Turns out your url is incorrect. It has to be

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://tonyg:password@localhost:5672/vir_host'
```

Now you are connecting via localhost and it works fine. If you want to connect remotely, it wont work. Your account is just a guest account and it doesn't have admin privileges. So that user has to connect via locahost ONLY. If you want that user to access from a virutal host, you need to give him privileges to do so.

Run this command to give user admin privileges.

```
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags tonyg administrator
```

You can read [more about this here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html).

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz forgot that he is connecting via localhost only.